# How to make an instant messenger without spamming the database

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I am currently working on an instant messaging system. But, I have a problem with the optimization.
Here is my current code:

```
<script>
   setInterval('load_messages()', 500);
   function load_messages(){
       $('#messages').load('loadMessages.php');
   }
</script>
```

Apart from the fact that, it is better to use an AJAX request to ask only for messages after a defined timestamp. Is there a way to pass a packet from the sender's page to the receiver to refresh to avoid spamming the database.
Here is a schema explaining what I would like to do:
[image]
Is there a way in php, apache or javascript to do this?

Thanks for reading

Comment: You're doing short-polling. With your current setup, you can consider long-polling. Besides that, this is 2000s technology. There are things like websockets and SSE that does exactly what you need, but a million times more efficient.

Comment: tons of tutorials out there with websockets and chat apps

Comment: What you likely want in the mix is an AMQP queuing system like RabbitMQ that handles distributing relevant messages to interested consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you use is called short-polling. It's basically spamming the server until the server has something new to show you. Looks something like:

```
Client: cookie?
Server: no
Client: cookie?
Server: no
Client: cookie?
Server: no
Client: cookie?
Server: yes; here's the cookie: 
Client: cookie?
Server: no
...
```

This is really inefficient, as you understood yourself; I don't know of any websites that still use short-polling.

You have other options. The easiest one (given you are using PHP) is long polling. Basically, you send a request, and the server just stalls the request, and once a new message comes the server sends the response back. This allows you to get messages immediately and not send so many messages:

```
Client: tell me when you have a cookie...
[loads for 1m 32s]
Server: the cookie has come [sends response]
Client: tell me when you have a cookie...
...
```

However, Apache handles concurrent requests by creating a new thread per request. So if you have 2 users in your chat, that's fine. But let's say you have many rooms and a total of 100,000 users long-polling your server. Your server probably can't handle that many threads and will crash. (NodeJS is very popular for realtime applications for its event-driven architecture and built-in asynchronism.)

---

But there are other much, better, options:

1. Websockets: this is basically a persistent (that is until the connection is manually closed) connection between the client and server, so the client doesn't have to bug the server so much. Whenever the server has a message, it sends it to the client immediately and vice versa. [Here's a good article](https://sookocheff.com/post/networking/how-do-websockets-work/). This is the most popular solution to realtime apps, and implemented by most chat apps like Discord or Slack.
2. SSE (server sent events): basically, instead of the client asking the server for data, the server can send data to the client. Here's [another article](https://ably.com/topic/server-sent-events) if you want to know how it works.

**Your context:** SSE is quite easy to implement in PHP without extra libraries; [here's an example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#sending_events_from_the_server). Websockets, on the other hand, are a bit more complex to set up (may require a third-party library like [rachet](http://socketo.me/)), but because of how well it works that's probably what I would consider.

**Your question:** *Is there a way to pass a packet from the sender's page to the receiver to refresh to avoid spamming the database?* If I were to exactly answer your question, SSE.